# Derivation of the Dirichlet L-series of order $1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I would like to know how the Dirichlet L-series(of order $1$) were derived. I independently found sequences analogous to the Dirichlet L-series using a property from: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4776903

Basically it was proved that $k-\sin(x)=k\cdot(1-\dfrac{1}{x_{root1}})(1-\dfrac{1}{x_{root2}})(1-\dfrac{1}{x_{root3}})\cdots$, For $|k|<1$

For instance, $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\sin(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\left(1-\dfrac{4x}{\pi}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{4x}{3\pi}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{4x}{5\pi}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{4x}{7\pi}\right)
\cdots$

By taking the logarithm of both the sides, we get:

$\log{(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\sin(x))}=\log{(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}})}+\log\left(1-\dfrac{4x}{\pi}\right)+\log\left(1-\dfrac{4x}{3\pi}\right)+\log\left(1+\dfrac{4x}{5\pi}\right)+\log\left(1+\dfrac{4x}{7\pi}\right)
\cdots$

Differentiating and substituting $x=0$ reveals:

$\dfrac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}=1+\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{1}{5}-\dfrac{1}{7}+\dfrac{1}{9}+\cdots$

This is apparently $L_{-8}(1)$ according to https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletL-Series.html (31st formula). One could replace $\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}$ with any constant $k,(|k|<1)$ to derive other Dirichlet L-series of order $1$.
I would like to know if this is indeed how the Dirichlet L-series were derived and if my derivation is novel.

I have searched online for the derivation, however I couldn't find any references to the derivation of the series.

I would greatly appreciate any derivations of the Dirichlet L-series of order $1$ :)

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "derivation of Dirichlet series or order $1$". Are you interested in deriving explicit formulae for $L(1,\chi)$, where $\chi$ is a nontrivial Dirichlet character? Such formulae go by the name of class number formulae, and they were originally obtained by Dirichlet himself.

Comment: Oh thanks for clarifying. I've asked mathstackexchange a couple of times for the derivation but to no avail, probably because of my wording. I would greatly appreciate it if you could provide me a proof of just one specific case:$L(1,-8)=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$, Since I'm trying to work out an alternate proof of the Basel problem :)

Comment: See my post below for the general formula (with a pointer to its proof) and how it gives the value of $L(1,\chi_{-8})$.

Comment: The m.se post was https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4777670/derivation-or-proof-of-the-dirichlet-l-series-of-order-1, and you waited all of five hours after you posted there before posting here, and you didn't inform either site of your post to the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $d$ is a negative fundamental discriminant, then
$$L(1,\chi_d)=\frac{\pi}{(2-\chi_d(2))\sqrt{-d}}\sum_{t=1}^{\lfloor -d/2\rfloor}\chi_d(t).$$
Here $\chi_d$ denotes the quadratic Dirichlet character $\left(\frac{d}{\cdot}\right)$. For a proof, see the proof of Theorem 3.9 in Section 10.3 of Rose: A course in number theory (2nd ed.).

**Example.** For $d=-8$ the above formula gives that
$$L(1,\chi_{-8})=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{8}}(1+0+1+0)=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}.$$

Comment: Thanks a ton :) However I can't for the life of me find a free copy of the 2nd edition of the book :( Guess I'll have to buy it

Comment: @SoapEatr There are similar formulae for every primitive Dirichlet character, and they can be found in many textbooks. See for example Theorem 67 in Fröhlich-Taylor: Algebraic number theory. Also, books are usually not free, but you can borrow them for free from a library.